# php obstart() ,$output2= ob_get_clean();

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I have used  ob_start() and  $output2= ob_get_clean() in all my previous programs But all of sudden, for this current program I have faced "undefined variable $output2" when I run program. I would appreciate if some one have a look

code:

```
<ul>
<?php
require_once "classes/DBAccess.php";
// remoteserver I used db.php Elh wants to get database setting from *** for the first time, early bird
include "settings/db.php";
$db = new DBAccess($dsn, $username, $password);
$pdo = $db->connect();
$sql = "select categoryName, categoryId from category";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$rows = $db->executeSQL($stmt);
$rows = $pdo->query($sql);
foreach ($rows as $row):
$id = $row["categoryId"];
$name = $row["categoryName"];
?>
<li><a href="hype.php?id=<?= $id ?>"><?= $name ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;
ob_start();
$output2= ob_get_clean();
include "templates/layout.html.php";
$pdo = null;
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: you must use $output2= ob_get_clean();
 after echoed variable

Comment: `ob_start();` should probably be at the top of the file. under the `include()` line

Comment: @saeed arab sheybani , $output2 would be echoed on templates/layout.html.php somewher. at the right place that it needs to be echoed, i can see undefined varaiable

Comment: @raxi: it is the way that i do all the time: at the end of program, i include it and it normally works

Comment: I doubt it. output buffering works by intercepting all output; so any output that comes before `ob_start()` will not be included. basically, anything **in between** `ob_start` and `ob_end_clear();` is intercepted. Since the 2 statements follow eachother here, you're not intercepting anything at all.

Comment: There is HTML output before this PHP code block and, as pointed out, the `ob_start` is near the end... it should be before any content is written

Comment: thanks a lot Raxi and Abronsius. should tick it as solved do not know how, Now I have another layout which is the file that u helped me to create. seems I need to use it as a layout as previous one was warning undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output buffering works by intercepting all output; anything in between `ob_start()` and ob_end_clear() is intercepted; any output that precedes `ob_start()` is not.

In this case, since the 2 statements follow each other, you're not intercepting anything at all.